# What if the Triassic-Jurassic Extinction Never Happed?

Tags: biology, evolution, alternate-history, prehistoric-times, reptiles

The Mesozoic era is mostly known for dinosaurs dominating the majority of the terrestrial niches for nearly the entire duration. Something lesser known is that the Triassic was actually mostly dominated by Pseudosuchians in terrestrial environments, and they filled nearly all the niches the dinosaurs would a couple dozen million years later.

This includes large armoured herbivorous [Aetosaurs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aetosaur), huge relatively-slow apex predators such as [Saurosuchus](http://www.prehistoric-wildlife.com/species/s/saurosuchus.html), quicker predators that sometimes held a bipedal stance like [Orthinosuchus](http://www.prehistoric-wildlife.com/species/o/ornithosuchus.html) (which at one time was mistaken for a Theropod!), slender erect fast-running predators like [Litargosuchus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litargosuchus), toothless beaked bipedal runners that resembled Ornithomimid dinosaurs like [Effigia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effigia), unusual forms suited to hunt in shallow-water areas like [Anatosuchus](https://paulsereno.uchicago.edu/exhibits_casts/african_crocs/anatosuchus/), and many others.

Dinosaurs at this time were mostly small theropods such as [Coelophysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coelophysis) that lived in the shadows of the pseudosuchians and early herbivorous prosauropods. Dinosauria didn’t massively diversify until the Triassic-Jurassic extinction when almost all pseudosuchians except for the smaller Crocodylomoroha, descendants would eventually become the Crocodylia that exist today, and major niches were open for Dinosauria to take.

So with my title question in mind, what do you think the Jurassic and Cretaceous world would look like if pseudosuchians were never removed from their niches? What forms would they diversify into? Would dinosaurs remain relatively small and avoid competition with pseudosuchians or would some groups develop to have features to even push pseudosuchians from their places? Would birds have even developed at all? If more dinosaurs remained small and ground-dwelling, would non-avian dinosaurs have survived the K-T extinction (assuming the K-T extinction still happens) along with mammals? How different would the Cenozoic world be?

Comment: Too much to calculate, but assume that  mammals would have remained small rat like animals... And some dinosaurs would evolve swimming and go full aquatic (it was about to happen but they died)

Comment: Herbivore dinosaurs would have been harder to kill, therefore predators would have evolved to be better at killing and so on for an endless vicious cycle. That's how the killing machine known has the honey badger was born... Now just imagine a sauropod version of that little crazy killer.

Comment: This is likely to be closed as too broad - as stated, you want to know how all the animals in the world would evolve in competition with each other.  Maybe if you ask a question about certain animals on an isolated island environment it might be answerable, although still very speculative.

Comment: Questions asking what would be the effect of an event upon the world are too broad for this site.

Comment: this would either be a be a dissertation or pure opinion. the answer it any what if X extinction did not happen is always a big shoulder shrug.